# Android Native Debugging

Tags: android, exploit

I'm currently working a project to investigate the security inherit with Android. A part of my project is to perform an overflow of the stack and execute a local shell. 
I've created an exploitable application in native c, that is dynamically linked, installed it and executed it.

I'm having trouble using GDB. I want to know the location of the system and exit call addresses, using the command "p system". GDB keeps giving me an error "no symbol table". I've gave GDB the correct paths before attaching to the process and used the "shared" command. I'm really struggling, Has anyone got any clue to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your native C application was compiled without the debug information. Try to compile your native code with `'-static -g'` options. Also, add to the native code a call to `system()` just to get this code disassembled in GDB.